# Copy and Paste From PDF to Emacs as Plain Text

Tags: org-mode, copy-paste, pdf, yank

Here is my problem:

I often copy text from a PDF (let's say one that is nicely formatted or scanned cleanly) and like to post it in an active org-mode file I have for academic research. However, pasting it with `C-y` typically inherits a lot of the new lines that PDF text tends to carry, requiring me to fix the text manually.

I've checked around for a solution to this problem, but the closest I found was a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5194494) on overflow, but it only works partially. It requires that I select the newly pasted text with `C-x C-x`, call `replace-string` with `C-q C-j RET RET`.

This typically removes most of the new lines effectively, but will often eliminate the space between two words that were on the end of the previous line and the first on the next (example would be 'betweentwo' in this sentence).

Any common fix to this? If possible, I would like a general solution that allows me to paste text from any source as simply plain text. I'm using Linux and emacs 24.5 for clarification. I don't think any of my own configurations are in conflict, but if my init file is wanted, I can post that on request.

EDIT: Pictures to show the problem.

Here's sample text of a pdf I want to copy. It's either a direct PDF export or a very clean scan, so I have no problem copying text accurately to my clipboard (No incorrect words, symbols, etc).

[image: Sample Text]

Here's what it looks like pasted `C-y` in emacs (org-mode on). Notice how it doesn't just let the lines wrap naturally. This is actually a cleaner yank than most, but the problem is still present.

[image]

Here's what it looks like after I use the make-shift method I linked in the original post. As of now, I'm re-highlight the region with `C-x C-x` and then use `ispell-region` to methodically correct the words combined together.

[image]

**Solution**: YoungFrog's answer below clarified my problem. TL;DR, `M-q`, fill-column, does well to reformat the text I yank from PDFs into paragraphs of length determined by emacs' `fill-column` (70 by default).

In addition, I was using `visual-line-mode`, which can make `fill-column` look like it's not working right since the minor-mode is intended to visually wrap text with "soft new lines", as YoungFrog also pointed out.

A useful package that combines `visual-line-mode` with the formatting benefits of `fill-column` is `visual-fill-column`, [available on MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/visual-fill-column).

Comment: I suspect this has less to do with Emacs and more how text is represented in a PDF (spoiler: messy) document.  Not too surprising if you consider that it's essentially a print preview format, so as long as the document looks right, how its contents are represented is less of a concern...

Comment: I totally agree. I used to use Microsoft Word extensively for public policy related work and had to deal with it. That said, I was able to find macros for MSWord that easily fixed the problem with a single function key press. Hopefully someone has a similar configuration and will see this.

Comment: In principle, does this 2-step process work: 1., replace the new lines with spaces, 2. fill-region on the selected text?

Comment: I don't have that in my init file. Would that be the function from this emacs wiki [link](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillRegion)? Also, how would I modify the procedure I posted above to replace new lines with spaces instead?

Comment: Does M-q not work good enough? If so please give examples of text.

Comment: @YoungFrog `M-q` wouldn't work if there are several subsequent line-breaks, but other than that, this would by my strategy too.

Comment: I've posted an update to give a visual example of what my problem looks like just for clarity.

Also, I tried the `M-q` method just now, and it actually works close to what I would like! It formats the text into a coherent block, but it makes the text into a block with lines shorter than they need to be. Is there any way to change the command so that it allows natural line wrapping?

Comment: Okay, progress @YoungFrog and @wvxvw. I tested that `M-q` command with a much longer yank and it definitely avoids the problem of combining words along newline breaks. I've posted what that looks like above. Is there any way to have emacs automatically change `set-fill-column` to the line length used by the rest of emacs/org-mode? That would solve this immediately. Thanks for the feedback so far, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Zaile it is not clear to me what you're asking with respect to `fill-column`. There is no reason for it to be different in that specific buffer if you didn't modify it yourself (unless you activated a mode which does it for you).

Comment: If you didn't see the last picture I posted, that's what I'm alluding to. The process I use currently results in a paragraph with lines that take the full column length given by org-mode, dependent on the current level of indentation. `M-1`, on the other hand, solves all of my problems with a single command but results in a paragraph with a column length 1/2 of the current indentation level.

Comment: I actually looked around more, and it seems that visual line mode was to blame. I like to be able to write the full length of the visible buffer for org-mode but `M-q` is set to 70 by default. I'm going to try setting it to some length adjusted to my screen and font size and see how that works out. From the looks of things, this should work as a solution if it goes as intended.

Comment: Indeed it's related to `visual-line-mode` : `M-q` does not rely on visual line mode and instead adds hard newlines in your text to wrap before reaching `fill-column` characters on each line. OTOH, visual line mode arranges to visually wrap text at the right margin, so that your text *seems* to have a newline, but in fact it doesn't. This is sometimes called "soft newline".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `M-q` (which runs the command `fill-paragraph`) : it will refill the paragraph according to the current value of `fill-column` by removing/adding hard newlines at the right spots for you.  You can use `C-x f` to change the value of `fill-column`.

If you prefer to avoid hard newlines at all (e.g. because you rely on `visual-line-mode` and `word-wrap`), you can set `fill-column` to a ridiculously large value (like 99999), or let `unfill-paragraph` or `unfill-region` do that for you. Those functions are available on emacswiki as you already noticed in a comment :

- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillParagraph
- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillRegion

Comment: Thank you very much clarifying those issues for me. I don't know how all the rules work on stackoverflow yet, but in addition to your advise/solution, I also found a MELPA package called [`visual-line-column-mode`](http://melpa.org/#/visual-fill-column) that makes `visual-line-mode` wrap at `fill-column` when reached AND at the edge of the window. Together, I still get the visual benefit of `visual-line-mode` while also maintaining a healthy column length/formatting.